# Euclidean Dirac Lagrangian is NOT Hermitian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

In $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the Euclidean metric, there are two entirely independent Dirac spinors, which I write as $\psi$ and $\overline{\psi}$.

This is because the universal double cover of the Euclidean group $E[4]$ is $SU(2) \times SU(2)$.

Also, the Euclidean Dirac operator $i \gamma^j\partial_j$ is known to be Hermitian (self-adjoint on a suitable domain, to be more precise).

For me, the naive Euclidean Dirac Lagrangian is
\begin{equation}
L_{E}=\overline{\psi}[i \gamma^j\partial_j+M]\psi
\end{equation}
where $M$ is some $4 \times 4$ mass matrix.

However, this Lagrangian $L_{E}$ is NOT Hermitian, since the two spinors are completely indepedent of each other.

The Minkowski Dirac Lagrangian is, on the other hand, Hermitian (up to a divergence term) since one spinor is the Dirac adjoint of the other.

Is my naive $L_{E}$ wrong? However, it clearly appears in textbooks and literature. Could anyone please clarify?

Comment: The action is complex -- that's fine. It is hard to simulate on the lattice though. Recall that lorentzian unitarity becomes euclidean reflection positivity.